# Excel's random number generator not random at all?

Tags: vba, excel, testing, statistics

I'm triying to test wheter Excel's random generator is really random or not, that's why I'm using [Wald's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald%E2%80%93Wolfowitz_runs_test)

By so doing this I have obtained a p-value of 0 thus I have not to accept null hypotesis i.e the sample is not random.

My question is:

1) **Am I making some mistake either coding or interpreting?**

Code:

```
    'By Julio Jesús Luna moreno
'jlqmoreno@gmail.com
Option Base 1
Sub WALDTEST()
 Dim x, r(), i, n, mu, sigma, plus(), minus(), k, h, f, j, phi, rplus, rminus, rachas() As Variant
  Dim w As Double, flag As Boolean
  n = 1000: k = 0: h = 0: flag = False: rplus = 0: rminus = 0: j = 0: phi = 0
  Set f = Application.WorksheetFunction
  ReDim r(n)
  For i = 1 To n
  Randomize
   x = Rnd()
    r(i) = IIf(x >= 0.5, 1, 0)
     Debug.Print r(i)
 Next i
  k = r(1)
   h = 2
 Do While h <= n
  Do Until flag = True Or h > n
    If r(h) = k Then
      phi = phi + 1
     flag = False
      h = h + 1
      Else
       flag = True
       k = r(h)
       h = h + 1
    End If
   Loop
    If phi >= 1 Then
     j = j + 1
      ReDim Preserve rachas(j)
       rachas(j) = r(h - 2)
        Debug.Print rachas(j)
     End If
     flag = False
    phi = 0
 Loop
rplus = j - f.Sum(rachas)
rminus = j - rplus
  mu = ((2 * rplus * rminus) / j) + 1
  sigma = (mu - 1) * (mu - 2) / (j + 1)
   w = f.Norm_S_Dist((j- mu)/Sqr(sigma), False)
    Debug.Print w
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a reason for the incremental indent?

Comment: @ThunderFrame no, i just think it looks nice

Comment: 'Dim x, r(), i, n, mu, sigma, plus(), minus(), k, h, f, mediana As Variant' only the last variable is explicitly declared. The others are all implicit variants. That's bit me before.

Comment: @IvenBach I have corrected this

Comment: You misunderstand Wald's test.

Comment: I dont believe it's that complicated. Why so many variables, and which one counts the **number of runs**? Besides, I believe 1000 rolls is far from enough for this test.

Comment: @A.S.H any improvement will be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it would be implemented.

1- We count the number of runs; incremented each time a flip in the picked value is observed

2- We check the resulted number of runs against the normal distribution corresponding to the hypothesis of independence (the null hypothesis). Precisely, we want the probability that the obtained number of runs be "that far" from the average. Note: it's a **two-tailed** test

3- To compute this probability you should use the *cumulative* normal distribution, that is, set the parameter `cumulative` to `true`

```
Sub WaldWolfowitz()
  Randomize
  Dim nRuns As Long ' counts the number of runs
  Dim x As Long ' a randomly picked value, 0 or 1
  Dim lastX As Long: lastX = -1 ' memorizes the last picked value to count runs
  Dim N(0 To 1) As Long ' array holds the number of picks of 0 and 1

  Dim i As Long, r As Double
  For i = 1 To 1000000
    r = Rnd
    x = IIf(r < 0.5, 0, 1)
    N(x) = N(x) + 1
    If x <> lastX Then nRuns = nRuns + 1
    lastX = x
  Next

  ' Distribution of the number of runs in the case
  ' the picks are independent (the null hypothesis)
  Dim mu As Double, variance As Double, sigma As Double, p As Double, z As Double
  mu = 1 + ((2 * N(0)) / (N(0) + N(1))) * N(1) ' rewrote it this way to avoid overflow
  variance = (mu - 1) * (mu - 2) / (N(0) + N(1) - 1)
  sigma = Sqr(variance)

  ' The p-test. We calculate the likelihood that the resulted number of runs
  ' be "that far" from mu. Notice in the calculation below:
  ' - We compute the absolute value of diff because it's a "two-tailed test"
  ' - We calculate the "tail" area under the normal curve from that point
  '   and we multiply it by two
  ' - The parameter "Cumlative:=True" for Norm_S_Dist to calculate the area under the normal curve
  z = Abs(nRuns - mu) / sigma
  p = 2 * (1 - WorksheetFunction.Norm_S_Dist(z, True))

  Debug.Print mu, sigma, nRuns, z, p
End Sub
```

p.s. I'll leave it to you to run the tests and interpret them. My own tests did not reject the null hypothesis of independence, although I was not much satisfied with them...

Answer (score 1):

- Excel's random number generator is not random - it's only pseudo-random.  (As are most computer generated random numbers.)
- Although the random numbers are usually sufficiently random for most purposes, you can see how non-random the numbers are if you write some code such as:

  ```
  Sub RndTest()
      Dim r(0 To 9999, 0 To 9999) As Long
      Dim i As Long
      Dim x As Long
      Dim y As Long
      For i = 1 To 100000000
          x = Int(Rnd() * 10000)
          y = Int(Rnd() * 10000)
          r(x, y) = r(x, y) + 1
      Next
      Cells(1, 1).Resize(10000, 10000).Value = r
      Columns("A:NTP").AutoFit
  End Sub
  ```

  You will need to be a bit patient while running that code, as it is generating 100,000,000 pairs of random numbers and allocating them to 100,000,000 cells.  But the pattern produced at the end is quite nice to look at.

  A lot of the problem is due to the fact that the random numbers produced in VBA are only a `Single` precision number, which only contains about 6 significant digits.

Comment: Interesting. Do you know any programming language which has a "real" random number generator?

Comment: @Moreno - to be "really" random, I believe it will need to be based on something random, which implies that some "non-programmed" input needs to be used as part of the calculation.  E.g. I think the decay of radioactive material could be used? Or maybe fluctuations in power supply levels?  So generating a "real" random number is more a hardware issue than a software issue.  (But I'm definitely not an expert on this subject.  Perhaps read [the wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation).)

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a correction to your code. Your calculation for mu is incorrect.

```
mu = ((2 * f.Count(plus) + f.Count(minus)) / n) + 1
```

should be

```
mu = ((2 * f.Count(plus) * f.Count(minus)) / n) + 1
                         ^
                         Note the change here
```

I think also your randomize command should occur outside of and before the for/next loop. I'm not sure how this will affect the outcome.

Comment: @Moreno - and, FWIW, "standard deviation" is the square root of "variance"

Answer (score 0):

You can also test it by flipping a coin.

> [*Actual experiments have shown that the coin flip is fair up to two
>   decimal places and some studies have shown that it could be slightly
>   biased*](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/153076/is-tossing-a-coin-a-fair-way-of-randomising-a-group-into-two-groups)

Here is a quick code for testing this (not the best but works as intended):

```
Sub flip()
Dim coin, i, j, zero, one, totalzero, totalone As Long
Dim averagezero, averageone As Double
For i = 1 To 100
    For j = 1 To 100
        coin = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, 1)
        If Value = 0 Then
            zero = zero + 1
        ElseIf Value = 1 Then
            one = one + 1
        End If
    Next j
    totalzero = totalzero + zero
    totalone = totalone + one
    zero = 0
    one = 0
Next i
averagezero = totalzero / 100
averageone = totalone / 100
Debug.Print "Average Zero Count: " & averagezero
Debug.Print "Average One Count: " & averageone
End Sub
```